# How to solve this Error: Cannot find module 'import-local'

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'import-local'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
```

I am getting this when i run npm run start command to run my project forkify.

Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:864:13)
    at convertBlockScopedToVar (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping\lib\index.js:139:13)
    at PluginPass.VariableDeclaration (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping\lib\index.js:26:9)
    at newFn (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:193:21)
    at NodePath._call (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:90:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:146:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:85:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:144:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:90:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:146:19)
    at Function.traverse.node (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:94:17)
    at traverse (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:76:12)
    at transformFile (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:88:29)
    at runSync (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:45:3)
    at runAsync (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:35:14)
    at process.nextTick (E:\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transform.js:34:34)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

I am getting this in the console of my index.html file

Comment: Have you installed it?

Comment: run npm install first

Comment: Yes after running and installing babel i get that.

Comment: @shubhamchitre have you find a solution for the error ? (beside installing import local yourself, manually, which is a solution)

Answer (score 1):

First, run

```
npm i
```

then run

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was using [**lerna**](https://lerna.js.org/) for the coordination of multiple packages.

let say, you have a project structured like this.

```
root
├── package.json
└── packages
    ├── first-project
    │   └── package.json
    └── second-project
        └── package.json
```

then, you have to first run `npm i` on the **root folder**, and then `npm i` into the project you want to work on before being able to run `npm run build`.

*Lior already said it in the comment, but it may help somebody*